# How can I simplify my digital processes to more efficiently get my work out there?

Tags: creative-process

I started out doing travel photography back in 2007 and for the first few years I used Flickr. I lacked a system or plan what to do with the photography other than to  tell a story about my travels and to back up a film project / blog. I floundered a lot when it came to figuring out a system for processing my images because of wasting a lot of time with different systems like Picasa, Flickr, (an their online organizing systems) and online stores where you could 'sell' your images but then they went bust or faded out of significance.

This lead to me having to spend a lot more time on web development to earn money, and partly as a frustration with the time wasted on other services. I came up with a very simple portfolio site (http://www.andywelchphotography.co.uk) but I've not done anything with it for ages because the process of putting images on there is very time consuming as it is static manual site.

I would like to know how I can get more of a balanced approach to the digital processing of photos in lightroom, and weighing up the pros and cons of putting work online vs getting out and about to showcase my work.

I use Adobe lightroom so part of my problem is possibly improving my process here.

I gleaned some answer to my question from this question: [Will a Facebook photo page increase my visibility as a photographer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/65667/will-a-facebook-photo-page-increase-my-visibility-as-a-photographer/65684#65684)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the type of work you want to be doing I would encourage you to not have a site at all or keep it basically how it is --- not updating it often.

The main reason I'm saying this is you look like you're trying to do photo essays and photo journalism. This stuff needs to be submitted to publications, galleries, and showcases to try and get featured. Most of which will require whatever you submit to have not been published before.

If you put on facebook, you put on behance, you put it on your own site or instagram or anywhere else then you can't submit to many of your key targets.

You should be focused entirely on that and then once you get stuff published create a page on your site with a list of publications and screenshots / scans of the articles (links are good, but if the link goes down you're in trouble).

---

To your second question about getting better with Lightroom --- why? You could build a relationship with someone to do the processing for you at a reasonable price. This lets you focus your time on the things you enjoy and are good at. Don't think you have to do everything. Check out this article / video for example - [FStoppers: Three Things You're Doing Wrong When Retouching](https://fstoppers.com/education/three-things-youre-doing-wrong-when-retouching-127096).

Comment: That's a good point. It would depend a lot on whether you are trying to get existing work published or get publications to commission new work. I think the smart thing in this case it to try to find role models and understand how and why they are using the web. For example, it's hard to argue that someone like Lindsay Addario is hurting herself by showing work on her site. But she's probably not scooping her potential outlets either. It's, or course, easier once you have some published work you can show.

Answer (score 2):

There's kind of a lot of questions hidden in here, so it's hard to know how to approach this. But let me just say one thing unequivocally: if you have a static website with pages that are difficult to update, you are doing it wrong. A website that is easy to update needs to be your first step because you need to keep it fresh and you need to be able to try different ideas and measure how they perform. Unless you *love* web design you should sign up for one of the many great sites like squarespace.com or aphotofolio.com and move on ([here's why](http://www.photo-mark.com/notes/design-your-own-website/)).

I think Lightroom is a terrific tool for wrangling photos, but it's hard to give concrete advice because there are so many ways to work with it. I like to use keywords and star rating in concert with smart collections to focus on my favorite work from certain locations. From there it's easy to just export and upload to a gallery if you have an easy-to-use website admin interface.

As far as getting your work out there, 'out there' doesn't really exist.  You need identify specific people and organization who will pay you for your work and develop a concrete, actionable plan to reach them. If you want to work in a crowded field like fine-art photography or travel, you are competing with people who are sending out mailers, arranging in-person meetings, getting the right blogs to showcase their work, and trying to be very active in the community in which they hope to work. A good, current website is essential, but it's just the foundation. Your work is terrific, but the competition is committed and good at the level your work deserves to be published.

So stop thinking about some vague 'out there' and start identifying real, breathing human beings who you should get to know. Once you do that you can evaluate the different avenues like social media, conferences, direct mail, etc. to reach them.

Comment: I agree a lot with this but would go as far as saying don't even bother with a squarespace / wix / tumblr / behance / etc... or any site for that matter. In fact it might be detrimental.